# python CSV fileoutput data is crumble into one column instead of multiple column

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

So, I'm doing a web scraping using Beautiful Soup

Let say I want to store the data to csv for every loop below

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"product-img" })

filename = "result.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "Link,Image\n"
f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    items = container.findAll("a")

    for item in items:
        datalink = item.attrs['href']
        dataimg = item.attrs['src']

        f.write(datalink + "," + dataimg + "\n")

f.close()
```

When I open the csv file with excel ,
The data is crumble into 1 column instead of 2 column
What I got :

```
Column A  
Link,Image  
link1,img1  
link2,img2  
link3,img3  
link4,img4  
link5,img5
```

What Expected :

```
Column A       Column B  
Link           Image  
link1          img1  
link2          img2  
link3          img3  
link4          img4  
link5          img5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use a library.  In this case, Python's built-in [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

Longer answer: without the exact code, and the data input you're using, the best I can do is guess at the problem.  But, in short, due to edge cases and embedded quotes and commas, CSV is slightly more complicated than you think.  Use a library that has already sussed out the details.

Additionally, don't "C-think" with the file manipulation.  Use `with`.  That is:

```
# "Bad"
f = open('somefile', 'w')
f.write( data )
f.close()

# Good
with open('somefile', 'w') as f:
    f.write( data )
```

I'll leave it to the [docs (section 7.2)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), to explain why `with` is the (much) better path.

Finally, example code to get you on your way:

```
import csv

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"product-img" })

filename = "result.csv"
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csvwriter.writerow( ('Link', 'Image') )

    for container in containers:
        items = container.findAll("a")

        for item in items:
            datalink = item.attrs['href']
            dataimg = item.attrs['src']

            csvwriter.writerow( (datalink, dataimg))
```

Comment: I use the import csv, I just forgot to write it in the question

Comment: @phaphapha Your question code suggests you're writing raw strings and manually inserting commas.  Meanwhile, the `csv` module is rock-solid.  Build a list per row, then use `writerow()`.  That will work.  If not, then post your *exact* code and input.

Comment: Well , I follow exactly the tutorial from this youtube video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI

Comment: @phaphapha I've just glanced through the tutorial.  As far web scraping goes, good.  As far as other details go, it encourages some weak habits.  For starters, the two details pointed out in my answer: not using a CSV library and not using Python's with statement.  Take from each what you will.